# Debugging the python VM

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7

Is there a debugger that can debug the Python virtual machine **while it is running Python code**, similar to the way that `GDB` works with C/C++? I have searched online and have come across `pdb`, but this steps through the code executed ***by*** the Python interpreter, not the Python interpreter as its running the program.

Comment: Are you looking for something *at* the bytecode level, or below it?

Comment: And, if you're looking for something below it… do you want to debug a specific Python implementation (presumably CPython), or just "any implementation, whichever is most illuminating/easiest/etc."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to debug Python at the bytecode level, that's exactly what `pdb` does.

If you're looking to debug the CPython reference interpreter… as icktoofay's answer says, it's just a C program like any other, so you can debug it the same way as any other C program. (And you can get the source, compile it with extra debugging info, etc. if you want, too.)

You almost certainly want to look at [EasierPythonDebugging](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/EasierPythonDebugging), which shows how to set up a bunch of GDB helpers (which are Python scripts, of course) to make your life easier. Most importantly: The Python stack is tightly bound to the C stack, but it's a big mess to try to map things manually. With the right helpers, you can get stack traces, frame dumps, etc. in Python terms instead of or in parallel with the C terms with no effort. Another big benefit is the `py-print` command, which can look up a Python name (in nearly the same way a live interpreter would), call its `__repr__`, and print out the result (with proper error handling and everything so you don't end up crashing your `gdb` session trying to walk the `PyObject*` stuff manually).

If you're looking for some level in between… well, there *is* no level in between. (Conceptually, there are multiple layers to the interpreter, but it's all just C code, and it all looks alike to gdb.)

If you're looking to debug *any* Python interpreter, rather than specifically CPython, you might want to look at PyPy. It's written in a Python-like language called RPython, and there are various ways to use `pdb` to debug the (R)Python interpreter code, although it's not as easy as it could be (unless you use a flat-translated PyPy, which will probably run about 100x too slow to be tolerable). There are also GDB debug hooks and scripts for PyPy just like the ones for CPython, but they're not as complete.

Answer (score 8):

The reference implementation of Python, CPython, is written in C. You can use GDB to debug it as you would debug any other program written in C.

That said, Python does have a few little helpers for use in GDB [buried under `Misc/gdbinit`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Misc/gdbinit). It's got comments to describe what each command does, but I'll repeat them here for convenience:

- **`pyo`:** Dump a `PyObject *`.
- **`pyg`:** Dump a `PyGC_Head *`.
- **`pylocals`:** Print the local variables of the current Python stack frame.
- **`lineno`:** Get the current Python line number.
- **`pyframe`:** Print the source file name, line, and function.
- **`pyframev`:** `pyframe` + `pylocals`
- **`printframe`:** `pyframe` if within `PyEval_EvalFrameEx`; built-in `frame` otherwise
- **`pystack`:** Print the Python stack trace.
- **`pystackv`:** Print the Python stack trace with local variables.
- **`pu`:** Print a Unicode string.

It looks like the Fedora project has also assembled [their own collection of commands](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/EasierPythonDebugging) to assist with debugging which you may want to look at, too.

Comment: But if you've ever tried it, this is easier said than done, without helpers…

Comment: @abarnert: Good point. I guess Python's got their own set of bundled GDB commands, too (which the EasierPythonDebugging page you linked to linked to); I've added it/them to my answer.

Comment: Since I think this is exactly what the OP wanted, it's probably the answer that should have been accepted, instead of mine, which tried to cover this and various other things the question could have meant… But it's not like it'll be hard to find this answer if people search.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping my answer to this question is still relevant.

As rightly said in the above answers, you can debug the Cpython VM via any C debugger.

A solution I found was to debug via Visual Studio (not VS Code). (for Windows only)

(The below answer is a somewhat summary of the link
https://devguide.python.org/getting-started/setup-building/ )

You can clone the code from GitHub (https://github.com/python/cpython) and follow the instruction to build it in VS as stated here

(https://web.archive.org/web/20220907075854/https://cpython-core-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_cpython_windows.html)

Create a breakpoint inside python.c and you are good to go.

I hope it works out !!!